# What exactly happens when you assign self to delegate?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, swift-protocols

I'm new to Swift and I'm having a hard time understanding the purpose of assigning `self` to a delegate.  Part of the difficulty stems from the fact that delegate seems to be used in two different ways.

First is as means to send messages from one class to another when a specific event happens, almost like state management. Second is to enable "a class or structure to hand off (or delegate) some of its responsibilities to an instance of another type," as stated in [documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html).  I have a feeling that these two are fundamentally the same and I'm just not getting it.

```swift
protocol PersonProtocol {
    func getName() -> String
    func getAge() -> Int
}

class Person {
    var delegate: PersonProtocol?
    
    func printName() {
        if let del = delegate {
            print(del.getName())
        } else {
            print("The delegate property is not set")
        }
    }
    
    func printAge() {
        if let del = delegate {
            print(del.getAge())
        } else {
            print("The delegate property is not set")
        }
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, PersonProtocol {
    var person: Person!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        person.delegate = self
        
        person.printAge()
        person.printName()
    }
    
    func getAge() -> Int {
        print("view controller")
       return 99
    }
    
    func getName() -> String {
        return "Some name"
    }
}
```

What is the purpose of `person.delegate = self` in this case? Isn't `ViewController` already required to conform to `PersonProtocol` without it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have a feeling that these two are fundamentally the same

The first is a special case of the second. "send messages from one class to another" is just a specific way of "handing off some of its responsibilities". The "messages" are the "responsibilities"

> What is the purpose of `person.delegate = self` in this case?

Here, `person` delegates (i.e. hands off) some of its responsibilities to another object. It does this by sending messages to another object. First, it needs to identify which objects it can delegate these responsibilities to. This is achieved by requiring that its `delegate` conform to `PersonProtocol`, as `PersonProtocol` defines the messages that `Person` is going to send.

Next, `person` needs to know *exactly* which object it should send these messages to. This is what `person.delegate = self` does. Remember that `person` doesn't know anything about your `ViewController` until this point. Instead of `= self`, you could say:

```
person.delegate = SomeOtherClassThatConformsToPersonProtocol()
```

and `person` will send its messages to that object instead, and the methods in your `ViewController` won't be called.

> Isn't `ViewController` already required to conform to `PersonProtocol` without it?

Correct, but without it, `person` doesn't know which object it should send its messages to, and as a result, the methods in your `ViewController` won't be called.

---

Note that the `delegate` property should be declared as `weak` to avoid retain cycles. When you do `person.delegate = self`, you get a retain cycle: `self` has a strong reference to `person`, `person` also has a strong reference to `self` via the `delegate` property.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So `ViewController` is the delegate for the `Person` class that's able to invoke methods from `Person`? What value does this bring to `Person`? Or to `ViewController` for that matter?

Comment: @Kevvv `ViewController` is the delegate of `person`, correct. `Person` can now inform `ViewController` when it needs a name or an age. As you might have realised, that's not how a `Person` should work... A `Person` should know about their own age and name, instead of asking the `ViewController`... So the names you have given to your classes and protocols are quite a bad example of how to use the delegate pattern. A better example can be found in the documentation linked in your question. There, it's `SnakesAndLadders` informing its delegate when the game starts and ends etc.

Comment: An example from UIKit is `UITableViewDelegate` asking its delegate what the height of each row should be, via [tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614998-tableview).

Answer (score 4):

If you notice inside your Person class, delegate is nil. If you don't execute person.delegate = self, delegate will remain nil.

In other words, assigning ViewController to person.delegate allows Person to identify who the delegate is (i.e., have a reference to ViewController), and that way you can successfully execute statements like delegate?.getName() or delegate?.getAge() from the Person class.

Answer (score 2):

that means `Person` is not able to `getName()` and `getAge()` so `Person` class delegate that to other DataSource.
Lets say the your view controller has a data source class `PersonDataSource` which deal with API to get this information So

```
class PersonDataSource: PersonProtocol { 
    func getAge() -> Int {
        print("view controller")
       return 99
    }
    
    func getName() -> String {
        return "Some name"
    }
 }
```

so the view controller will looks like this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var person: Person!
    var personDataSource = PersonDataSource()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        person.delegate = personDataSource
        
        person.printAge()
        person.printName()
    }
}
```