# When/ How does swift call user created functions

Tags: swift, function, mapkit, mkmapview

Im currently learning how to code using swift. I created an app that simple displays the users location using map view.

In this code block, when does swift call the function locationManager()? I seem to have never called this function, yet it is running all the logic within it

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,
                      CLLocationManagerDelegate{
    
    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var AreaLbl: UILabel!
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(){
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
        print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
        let userLocation = locations.last
        let viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: (userLocation?.coordinate)!, latitudinalMeters: 600, longitudinalMeters: 600)
        self.map.showsUserLocation = true
        self.map.setRegion(viewRegion, animated: true)
        
    }
```

If there are any resources you recommend for learning swift please let me know!

Comment: [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62506166/what-exactly-happens-when-you-assign-self-to-delegate). Notice the line `locationManager.delegate = self`. That's the reason this works. That's where you tell the location manager that it should call _your_ `didUpdateLocations` method, when it decides to. In this case, `didUpdateLocations` will be called when the manager detects an update in location.

Answer (score 3):

First, a point of order. In Swift, the name of a function includes parameters. Your function isn't named `locationManager()`. It's named `locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)` (One unnamed parameter and one parameter named "didUpdateLocations".)

Now to your question.

iOS and Mac OS make pretty common use of the delegate design pattern. In that pattern, one object sets itself up to be another object's "delegate". That basically means that the delegate object agrees to wait by the phone for incoming phonecalls.

When you are an object's delegate, you agree to respond to a set of messages that might be sent to you (or functions that might be called.) You "conform to a protocol" that defines the messages you need to respond to. Some of those messages might be required and some might be optional.

It's not **Swift** calling your function, it's the OS. Specifically the location manager.

Your `viewDidLoad()` function includes the line `locationManager.delegate = self`.

That makes you the location manager's delegate.  That means that you conform to the [CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate). It tells the location manager that you are ready to accept messages (function calls) from the location manager that are defined by that protocol.

When you do that, and then you tell the location manager to start updating your location with the line `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()`, the location manager will start calling your `locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)` function at some future time when it detects a change to the device's location.

**That** is what is causing your `locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)` function to be called.